# How to select elements using protractor created by ng-repeat track by $index?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need to select the textbox created by ng-repeat and send some values using sendKeys Function. But I'am not sure about the method to select the  textboxes. Please suggest a method to accomplish this Or Should I use css selectors instead.

```
<div class="qst_input_hld ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in options track by $index">
<input type="text" class="input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="options[$index]" placeholder="Option 1" ng-class="isOptionEmpty[$index] ? 'error-border' : ''">
<!-- ngIf: $index > 1 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to locate the text input and, since there is a repeater there, I suspect there are multiple text boxes. Assuming you want to send keys to the first one, here is one option:

```
var desiredInput = element.all(by.repeater("option in options")).first().all(by.tagName("input")).first();
desiredInput.sendKeys("desired text");
```

Note that you *don't need to handle the `track by` part at all* - it is getting stripped away by Protractor ([source code reference](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9144494a28dac5a0409de4c5384e933f2d2f8156/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L149)).

Also note that I've just used the `by.tagName()` technique which may or may not work depending on if you have the other `input` elements there. You can be more strict and use a *CSS selector* instead, e.g. check the placeholder:

```
var desiredInput = element.all(by.repeater("option in options")).first().$('input[placeholder="Option 1"]');
```

And, if you want to send keys to input element for every item in the repeater, use [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
element.all(by.repeater("option in options")).each(function (elm) {
    var desiredInput = elm.$('input[placeholder="Option 1"]');
    desiredInput.sendKeys("desired text");
});
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning we don't need to handle track by at all.  I was looking for that confirmation in a google search, and it led me to this answer.  I'll ask the Protractor team for more documentation on this.

Comment: @Keith thanks! By the way, I've added a rule to the [`eslint-plugin-protractor` ESLint plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) that would warn if you do use extended repeater syntax inside `by.repeater()` locators. [Check it out](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/use-simple-repeaters.md).

Answer (score 0):

Provide a name and id attribute to your text boxes  :

```
<input ... name="your_textbox" id="textbox_{{index}}" />
```

And if you want to select all textboxes :

```
document.getElementsByName("your_textbox");
```

Specific textbox :

```
document.getElementById("textbox_"+i);   //i=index
```

Through Protractor :
First change the ng-model of your input box to :

```
<input type="text" class="input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="option" placeholder="Option 1" ng-class="isOptionEmpty[$index] ? 'error-border' : ''"> <!-- see ng-model=option -->
```

Then select it by using model :

```
var repeaterElements= element(by.repeater('option in options'));

repeaterElements.each(function(entry) {
    var input = entry.element(by.model("option"));
});
```

Comment: I actually mean to select the textboxes in Protractor E2E Testing Framework by using element(by.repeater). Is it possible.