# AngularJS ng-repeat track by $index and Protractor with Duplicates

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of strings, which I need to allow for duplicates.

```
vm.list = ["item","item","item","item","item"]
```

this is handled in the html with

```
<ul class="listItems>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list track by $index"></li>
</ul>
```

This displays fine in the DOM, no issues, but I run into problems when I try to protractor test the ng-repeat, since I can't unit test it.

So my test is something like.

```
Then("List items should contain {int} items.", function(listLength){
    return element(by.css(".listItems").all(by.repeater('item in ctrl.list track by $index')).then(function(list){
        return expect(list.length).equal(listLength);
    });
});
```

I run my tests and it fails with Expect 0 to be 5
But if I make them all unique it works fine, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you:

```
Then("List items should contain {int} items.", function(listLength){
    let list = element(by.css(".listItems").all(by.repeater('item in ctrl.list'));
    expect(list.count()).toBe(listLength);
});
```

Source: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count

Edit: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question, it appears `track by` does not work with duplicate values in an array. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat. You can substitute your own tracking function.

Here is an example of a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28232640/3111958

2nd Edit: After looking into it some more, protractor does not use the track by portion. I updated the code block to reflect that. Check out this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37535098/3111958

Comment: but 'track by $index' should handle duplicates as given in the documentations example <div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">  {{n}}  </div> which works when rendered in html but for some reason is failing in Protractor.

Comment: Actually it looks like you shouldn't be including the `track by $index` in the repeater, please see the edited answer.

Comment: Ya, I thought that too, but nope, that didn't work either :(

Comment: Hm, did you try testing it with a hardcoded list? Maybe the list isn't being populated at run time or maybe it isn't loaded in the DOM in time for protractor to inspect it.

Comment: Yes, its an odd one, it works find if you view the html normally, but trying to count the <li>'s in protractor is where it fails, it's like protractor can't render the ng-repeat correctly, again if I give it a list with no duplicates it work fine.  I've hit so many brick walls with this tool though, nothing surprises me now, its a bit of a dark art, which sometimes fails for what seems like, no good reason.